# Оптимизировать код в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть рабочий код в jQuery, который, как мне кажется, можно оптимизировать за счет условий `if` и `else`. Тем не менее, у меня не получилось это сделать, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Пример кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#female").click(function() {
    $("#showFemale").show();
    $("#showMale").hide();
    $("#who").hide();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#male").click(function() {
    $("#showMale").show();
    $("#showFemale").hide();
    $("#who").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showFemale">showFemale</div>
<div id="showMale">showMale</div>
<div id="who">who</div>
<button id="female" val="female">female</button>
<button id="male" val="male">male</button>
```

Comment: а как пытался-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так

```js
$("#female").click(function() {
       toggleIds(true);
      });
$("#male").click(function() {
     toggleIds(false);
    });

var toggleIds = function(show){
        $("#showFemale").toggle(show);
        $("#showMale").toggle(!show);
        $("#who").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showFemale">showFemale</div>
<div id="showMale">showMale</div>
<div id="who">who</div>
<button id="female" val="female">female</button>
<button id="male" val="male">male</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

По мотивам @Moonvvell

```js
$("#male, #female").click(function() {
  var isMale = this.id === "male";
  $("#showFemale").toggle(!isMale);
  $("#showMale").toggle(isMale);
  $("#who").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showFemale">showFemale</div>
<div id="showMale">showMale</div>
<div id="who">who</div>
<button id="female" val="female">female</button>
<button id="male" val="male">male</button>
```